# How to put Pin in 4 digits only when entering a PIN and how to verified it?

Tags: c#

I don't know the codes as I'm a beginner in c#, so could anyone help me with these? I want my `pin` to enter in **4 digits** only and re verified the `pin` to continue in the menu?

```
{
class program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        int amount = 1000, deposit, withdraw;
        int choice, pin = 0, x = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Pin Number ");
        pin = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("********Welcome to ATM Service**************\n");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Check Balance\n");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Withdraw Cash\n");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Deposit Cash\n");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Quit\n");
            Console.WriteLine("*********************************************\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your choice: ");
            choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n YOUR BALANCE IN Rs : {0} ", amount);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n ENTER THE AMOUNT TO WITHDRAW: ");
                    withdraw = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (withdraw % 100 != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n PLEASE ENTER THE AMOUNT IN MULTIPLES OF 100");
                    }
                    else if (withdraw > (amount - 500))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n INSUFFICENT BALANCE");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        amount = amount - withdraw;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n PLEASE COLLECT CASH");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n YOUR CURRENT BALANCE IS {0}", amount);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n ENTER THE AMOUNT TO DEPOSIT");
                    deposit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    amount = amount + deposit;
                    Console.WriteLine("YOUR BALANCE IS {0}", amount);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n THANK U USING ATM");
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n THANKS FOR USING OUT ATM SERVICE");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to StackOverflow. Despite the fact that you put a question mark in each sentence, I still can't understand what is your actual question. Try to rewrite it to be more clear. Also, please note, that StackOverflow is _not_ a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like this:

```
// read size (4) digits
private static string ReadPin(int size = 4) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);

  while (sb.Length < size) {
    var key = Console.ReadKey(true); // we don't want to show the secret pin on the screen

    // Uncomment, if you want to let user escape entering the PIN
    // if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) {
    //   return "";
    // } 

    if (key.KeyChar >= '0' && key.KeyChar <= '9') {
      sb.Append(key.KeyChar);

      Console.Write('*'); // let's show * instead of actual digit
    }
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}

...

// private: there's no need for Main to be public
private static void Main() {
  ...
  Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Pin Number ");

  int pin = int.Parse(ReadPin());
```

If you want to *verify* the given string (`pin`) which is expected to be of length `size`, you can try either *Linq*

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string pin = ...
  int size = 4;

  bool isValidPin = pin.Length == size && pin.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');
```

Or *regular expressions*:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  bool isValidPin = Regex.IsMatch(pin, $"^[0-9]{{{size}}}$");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int password; 
    int repassword

    Do{
    Console.WriteLine("\n Enter the password");
    password= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //first password
    string ps = Convert.ToString(password);
    }while(ps.Length!=4) //request the password if is not composed by 4 digits

    //menu part//
    Do{
    Console.WriteLine("\n Reinsert the password");
    repassword= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //reinsert password

    } while(repassword!=password)
```

Comment: Hi, he said the pin has to be only four digits

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work there's been an error in these code while(Convert.ToString(password).Length!=4)